# I'm a new to Python. I need help, I'm getting NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Tags: python

```
class Trapezoid:

    def __init__(self, h, a, b):
        self.h = h
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def getArea(self):
        return 0.5 (a + b) * h

small_trapezoid = Trapezoid(6, 3, 4)
print('The area of the trapezoid is', small_trapezoid.getArea())
```

Comment: return 0.5 (self.a + self.b) * self.h

Comment: When you're referencing class members, you need to use `self.a` and `self.b`. `a`, `b`, and `h` are scoped in self.

Comment: `self.a`, not `a`. Who does `a` belong to? `self`.

Comment: If you are new to the language, at the very least you should check out the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) where this would have been revealed

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to properly ask on this site.

Answer (score 1):

That's right, it's not defined. You meant `self.a`, as well as the other two.

```
return 0.5 (self.a + self.b) * self.h
```

Though then you have another error: `TypeError: 'float' object is not callable`

Comment: You are right, I got that error. How do I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: @Jay Is it supposed to be multiplication?

Comment: I need to follow this formula: Area = ½(a+b) × h

Comment: @Jay You need to actually tell it to do multiplication: `0.5 * (...`

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to access 'a', 'b' and 'h' values in the getArea method, you might want to change it to

```
    def getArea(self):
        return 0.5 (self.a + self.b) * self.h
```